# How to Extract datetime value with AM/PM && remember its position from string

Tags: c#

I've see
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911874/extracting-a-date-value-from-a-string/54600593). What if my string is `string x = "Tomorrow 04-26-19 09:14AM sunrise.";`, basically the datetime value is always in `mm-dd-yy hh:mm<AM/PM>` format. So I'd need to **extract** this value of `04-26-19 09:14AM` and **remember** the starting position which = 9.

Comment: Does it always occur after the first space and end before the last one. Otherwise, use a simple Regex to pick out the match, and then do a second pass using `string.IndexOf` (unless you need to do a million of these operations)

Comment: @Flydog57 - Even with a million operations your suggestion sounds quite fast.

Comment: @Flydog57 - Regex matches keep index anyway. So actually quite fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works nicely for me:

```
string x = "Tomorrow 04-26-19 09:14AM sunrise.";

var regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)");

var match = regex.Match(x);

if (match.Success)
{
    var prefix = x.Substring(0, match.Index);
    var value = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Value, "MM-dd-yy hh:mmtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    var suffix = x.Substring(match.Index + match.Length);
}
```

It's using `Regex` to find a potential `DateTime` string and then determines the prefix part of the string, the `DateTime` value, and the suffix part of the string.

It gives me:

```
"Tomorrow "
2019/04/26 09:14:00
" sunrise."
```

Answer (score -1):

If "tomorrow" and "sunshine" aren't necessarily always going to be present in a string like *x* but the format of this string will be similar, I'd probably split these strings according to the *space* character like this.

```
x.Split(' ')
```

with indices

```
string strDate = x.Split(' ')[1];
string strTime = x.Split(' ')[2];
```

& then join those sets of strings

```
string dt = $"{strDate} {strTime}";
```

& then probably use the DateTime.ParseExact functionality to craft an actual DateTime object out of what I parsed.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "MM-dd-yy hh:mmtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal)
```

I generally use assumelocal so that I know the time won't be UTC.
"tt" is a placeholder for AM or PM.

If this is something you'll have to do iteratively, then I would probably create a method for this, and then simply call it routinely.